# mat-tab inside mat-menu sometimes dot not display content correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am using angular 15.0.4

When puting a `mat-tab` inside a mat-menu, I sometimes observe a strange behavior: the content of the `mat-tab` is not displayed.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <mat-tab-group (click)="selectTab($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Affichage"> ABC </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Export"> DEF </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-menu>
```

See example below:

[image]

Corresponding stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzvnrv?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

What could cause this bug, and how to fix it?

Comment: Let me add a link to your post on github, so it's easier for SO-users to track the development on this issue (I'm almost certain it's a regression since the css sets a hidden tag for both tabs): https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26383

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem issue is with new material version
here is how i solved this issue
Add this in constructor

```js
private renderer: Renderer2
```

```js
function called on tab change
onTabChange(event){ let element = document.querySelector(.mat-tab-body-content[style*="visibility: hidden"]) if(element){ this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'visibility', 'visible'); this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'display', 'block'); } }
```

call this function in (selectedTabChange) change in mat-tab-group